# problem in Async Task implementation of httpconnection

Tags: android, http, android-asynctask

im working on posting a form to google server and getting the response in the form of html string and finally i put that string on webview to display result....i use the async task for this, progress dialog it shows but some times it shows me message to "force to close" without any changes i do in to code....that means prediction about output is unexpected... My code is like this......

```
public class Urlasync extends Activity {  
   WebView engine=null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
        new AddStringTask().execute();
    }

   class AddStringTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, HttpResponse>
    {
        HttpResponse end = null;
        String endResult = null;
        public static  final int TIMEOUT_MS=10000;
         HttpClient client=null;
         HttpPost post =null;
         List<NameValuePair> pairs=null;
         BasicResponseHandler myHandler=null;
         private final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(Urlasync.this);
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
             client = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), TIMEOUT_MS);
             HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(client.getParams(), TIMEOUT_MS);
             post = new HttpPost("http://www.google.com/m");
             pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
             pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hl", "en"));
             pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("gl", "us"));
             pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("source", "android-launcher-widget"));
             pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("q", "persistent"));
             try {
                    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
                    SystemClock.sleep(400);
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
             this.dialog.setMessage("starts...");
             this.dialog.show();

          }
        @Override
        protected HttpResponse doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

            try {
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
                    if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
         {
             return response;
         }
             end = response;
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {   //this exception is called
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return end;

        }
        @Override       
        protected void onPostExecute(HttpResponse params) {
             if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
                            this.dialog.dismiss();
                             }
                    if(params!=null)
         {
            String endResult=null;
            BasicResponseHandler myHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                try {
                    endResult = myHandler.handleResponse(params);

                } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
              engine = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
          engine.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://", endResult, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
                 engine.requestFocus(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
                      }
             Toast.makeText(Urlasync.this, "Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    }
```

suggestions with code are welcome
thank you..

Comment: What exception does occur? Please add the output of the log cat.

Comment: it says me to "force close"..

Comment: it says me that application stops unexpectedly..

Comment: Read about LogCat, here you can find a cause of your problem

Comment: exception is NullPointerException ..at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponceHandler.handleresponce

Comment: You'd better edit your question, adding the full stacktrace of an exception.

Comment: 04-13 15:08:49.184: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(381):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(BasicResponseHandler.java:69)

Comment: this is the stack trace..( i remove the toast in doInBackground)   Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception NullPointerException)) 
 BasicResponseHandler.handleResponse(HttpResponse) line: 69

Comment: Urlasync$AddStringTask.onPostExecute(HttpResponse) line: 104 
 Urlasync$AddStringTask.onPostExecute(Object) line: 1 
 Urlasync$AddStringTask(AsyncTask).finish(Object) line: 417

Comment: AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask, Object) line: 127 
 AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(Message) line: 429 
 AsyncTask$InternalHandler(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
 Looper.loop() line: 123 
 ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3647 
 Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method] 
 Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507 
 ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 839 
 ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 597 
 NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shan't do anything with UI in `doInBackground` (like showing `Toast`). Do it in `onPostExecute` or in `onProgressUpdate` instead.

Comment: in doInbackground i get the Httpresponce then in onPostExecute i parse it,show toast ans display that responce in webview... but i read some where that for async task require UI thread,  so where i put that one..

Comment: Remove your showing toast from `doInBackground` or move it to `onPostExecute`.

Comment: exception is NullPointerException ..at org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponceHandler.handleresponce

Comment: You do it in `doInBackground` too, but you shan't: `protected HttpResponse doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
...
             Toast.makeText(Urlasync.this, "Done execute!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               ...
`

Comment: Debug `onPostExecute` and find that `params` is null

Comment: yes dude,the params are null, so is there any problem in doInBackground becoz it returns httpresponce..

Comment: is it imp to check the response code of response to see it returns null

Comment: the problem is in the HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);

Comment: im behind the collage firewall ..i think because of this only the connection cant take place becoz log cat show me error anonymous name"google.com"